Ninja and a beach bum sidekick with a lot of pistols
I recall a TV series I used to watch with my dad. It was about an american ninja and his side kick who was a beach bum or sailor. One memorable scene is in a small area like an apartment living room and they are fighting bad guys and the beach bum pulled out a gun and the bad guy would kick it away so the the bum would pull out another gun and so on and so forth. This went on until the beach bum had pulled out like 10 pistols from different places on his body and then finally he punched the bad guy. It was a hilarious scene but the show was not a comedy. The bum's name may have been Skeet or scooter and I think it was located in Miami or somewhere near the ocean.
Any idea about what show this was? It was on in the early-mid 90's at the same time highlander TV series was running. I don't recall how many seasons it run (probably just one).

Raven it was on cbs i think lee majors was the beach bum set in Hawaii mid to late 90's one season if that.

Lasted 2 seasons - Suumer '92 and Spring '93

That's the one!

The Master was a TV series from the 80's that had a "loser" type of guy named Max Keller (Timothy Van Patten) traveling around in a van with John Peter McAllister (Lee Van Cleef) "The only Occidental-American to become a ninja," righting wrongs and fighting injustice. It's probably best know for having a young Demi Moore in an episode and getting a second life on Mystery Science Theater 3000. The specific scene you mentioned doesn't ring any bells, but this otherwise sounds pretty close.

Bonus point to the show for having two guys named "Van" traveling in a van.

Might it be "Kung-Fu: The Legend Continues" with the dad/ninja and son/cop fighting crime together in California? Fits your time period and some of your details. I don't recall the scene you describe, but seems like something that might have been on the show.


sorry, this was not it.
